# ¿Cómo eliminar el contenido de la consola desde el cursor hasta el principio?

Tags: bash, zsh

Hasta hace poco utilizaba Bash. Allí, puedes eliminar todo el contenido de la línea desde donde está el cursor hasta el principo de la línea apretando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

```
$ hola que tal estas
          ^
$ tal estas            # Ctrl+U
  ^
```

Y así lo indica el manual de Bash en [8.4.4 Killing And Yanking](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Killing.html):

> **unix-line-discard (C-u)**
>
> Kill backward from the cursor to the beginning of the current line.

Sin embargo, ahora uso `zsh` ([Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) en concreto) y esta funcionalidad ha desaparecido. Ahora cuando pulso <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> se elimina la línea entera. Si hago <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> se eliminan palabras de la siguiente forma:

```
 $ hola que_tal estas
               ^
 $ hola que_ estas        # Ctrl+U
            ^
 $ hola  estas            # Ctrl+U
        ^
```

¿Alguien sabe qué debo configurar para que Ctrl+U vuelva a eliminar todo desde el cursor hasta el principo de la línea?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como la programación no relacionado porque se trata del uso de computadora y no es específica para programadores.

Comment: @Gilles creo que todo lo relacionado con opciones de bash y zsh es pertinente aquí. Que de una forma u otra su uso sea "de consola" y no de programación no creo que sea la clave.

Comment: Votando para cerrar. Esto es similar a preguntar sobre la funcionalidad de un IDE, cosa que no está dentro del ámbito de SO.

Comment: @user1231958 no estoy de acuerdo con la comparación. Esto es Bash, zsh y sus opciones son opciones programáticas.

Comment: En realidad la pregunta si es on-topic en este sitio y en so SO en inglés: Por favor leer [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . Uno de los temas permitidos es **herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores;** lo cual claremente incluye los shells

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Al parecer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> en zsh cumpla la función `kill-whole-line` por defecto, lo que necesitas es que haga un `backward-kill-line`, intenta agregando esto a tu `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey \^U backward-kill-line
```

Cabe mencionar que la lista de comandos (o widgets) la puedes encontrar en el manpage de `zshzle` en la sección *STANDARD WIDGETS*

Para mayor referencia:

- [The Z-Shell Line Editor](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html)

Comment: Muy bien, ¡funciona! Muchas gracias.